# Find the Taylor expansion of $f(x-yh)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, taylor-expansion, self-learning

> Find the Taylor expansion of $f(x-yh)$.

The exercise don't say if $h$ and $y$ are variables too. I tried to do a Taylor series at $yh$

$$f(x)=f(x-y)+\frac{f'(x-yh)}{1!}(x-yh)+\frac{f''(x-yh)}{2!}(x-yh)^2...$$

But the answer says that Taylor expansion of $f(x-y)$ is

$$f(x-yh)=f(x)+hyf'(x)+\frac{1}{2}h^2y^2f''(x)+o(h^2)$$

Anyone can help me understand it?

Comment: Hm, I wanted to say its a textbook error, but it doesn't seem to be for any $x^n$.  Intriguing...

Comment: @SimpleArt This results is from a slide that I found in a course, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer, it seems obvious that they expand $f(x-\epsilon)$ around $\epsilon=0$. So, $$f(x-\epsilon)=f(x)-\epsilon  f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} \epsilon ^2 f''(x)+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ and replaced later $\epsilon$ by $hy$.

Not only the $x^n$ are missing (just as Simple Art commented) by it seems that there are also sign errors.

Also, what they give cannot be $O\left(h^2\right)$ but $O\left(h^3\right)$ instead.

We can bet that, once more, the textbook contains typo's.